# Does my DNS server knows about all external CNAME records pointing to me?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is the DNS server from my domain provider aware of all cname record existing in other DNS server and that are pointing to me as an external domain?

For example, if someone makes a CNAME record for **subdomain.example.com** in his DNS server like

```
subdomain IN CNAME www.mydomain.example
```

Will I find this line in my DNS at some point?

Comment: As said in the answer from TomTom no.  But if you log things like `ServerName` in your apache access logs you'll see it

Answer (score 2):

Only if someone asks your dns server to resolve `subdomain.example.com`, otherwise no - and your DNS server does not care.